# how to show floating widgets(edit text and buttons) in android

Tags: android, button, widget, android-edittext, floating

I want to show floating edit texts and buttons on screen in android e.g. look below the image, there are 3 edit texts and 2 buttons which are floating on current screen. I searched a lot on net but got nothing. So please anyone suggest how to do this, even some links will be useful.

[image]

Its Ok, if the widgets are not transparent, but it should give feel that they are floating on my current screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pop up or custom Alert dialog may solve your problem.

But simple solution is take another layout in xml of the activity. In that layout add those edittexts and buttons. Set its visibility to false. And when you want to show then, make layout's visibility to true.